# in c++ I have 2 struct and wants to pass to the same function

Tags: c++, function, struct

I would like to ask if is it possible doing the following in c++:

I have this 2 struct

```
struct RegistroPyF {
    int Fecha=0;
    int ups=0;

};
struct BuySigPyF {
    int columna=0;
    int fecha=0;

};
```

An I would like to pass it to a function.

```
void CreaTabla(struct ,const char *base, string accion){};
```

And calling like:

```
CreaTabla(RegistroPyF ,const char *base, string accion);
```

or

```
CreaTabla(BuySigPyF ,const char *base, string accion);
```

How could I define a structure in a function so when I call it I can use either of the struct?

Comment: Overloading would allow you to get the two calling notations; you just need to define two different functions that take the different structs as the first argument. That said, I have no idea what you are asking with _"How could I define a structure in a function so when I call it I can use either of the struct?"_. Could you clarify? Why would you be defining the structure in the function?

Comment: You need to be more specific on your function declaration.  There can be an unlimited quantity of `struct`, each one different.  Try something like `void CreaTabla(const RegistroPyF&, const std::string& base, const std::string accion);`

Comment: Since the members are in different orders, I would move the common code out of `CreaTabla` into a `CreaTabla_helper` and then have two overloads of `CreaTabla` to handle the struct specific code.

Comment: How would you know, in the function, which structure was passed?

Comment: I think this question needs to detail _the problem being solved_.  There are many ways to allow a function to take varying parameter types.  Which approach to use depends on _what you are trying to do_.  If the question is really "if it is possible", the answer is Yes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers.

Comment: to be more precise. I have several structs (just put two for example) with different types. The idea is to use one function to cread and manage a table that has the types of the struct as columns. So I wanted to use just one function to perform the task but give me the liberty to use whichever struct need.

Answer (score 0):

You could accept both:

```
void createTable(RegistroPyF *p1, BuySigPyF *p2, const char *base, string accion) {
}
```

And then call either like so:

```
RegistroPyF  registro;
BuySigPyF buy;

createTable(&registro, nullptr, "foo", "bar");
createTable(nullptr, &buy, "foo", "bar");
```

You could also use a void * and figure out what type it is, but I consider that dangerous.